# VBA - choose save as from the frame notification bar of internet explorer

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am trying to download a file with save as through the **frame notification bar** of internet explorer.
However after doing a lot of searches, I have only found solutions to click `save` on the frame notification bar.
So far I have been trying to save as the file on the sample site:

http://www.tvsubtitles.net/subtitle-114117.html

with the following code:

```vb
' Add referenses
' Microsoft Internet Controls
' Microsoft HTML Object Library
' UIAutomationClient (copy file from C:\Windows\System32\UIAutomationCore.dll to Documents Folder)

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx _
        Lib "user32" _
        Alias "FindWindowExA" ( _
        ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, _
        ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, _
        ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
        ByVal lpsz2 As String) _
        As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function FindWindowEx _
        Lib "user32" _
        Alias "FindWindowExA" ( _
        ByVal hWnd1 As Long, _
        ByVal hWnd2 As Long, _
        ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
        ByVal lpsz2 As String) _
        As Long
 #End If

Sub downloadfilefromeie()

    Dim subpage As InternetExplorer
    Dim objpage As HTMLDocument
    Dim o As CUIAutomation
    Dim h As LongPtr
    Dim fnb As LongPtr
    Dim e As IUIAutomationElement
    Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
    Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement
    Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern
    Dim strBuff As String
    Dim ButCap As String

    Set objshell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objallwindows = objshell.Windows
    Set subpage = New InternetExplorer
    For Each ow In objallwindows
        'MsgBox ow
        If (InStr(1, ow, "Internet Explorer", vbTextCompare)) Then
            'MsgBox ow.Hwnd & "  " & ow & "   " & ow.locationURL
            If (InStr(1, ow.locationURL, "tvsub", vbTextCompare)) Then
                Set subpage = ow
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Set objpage = New HTMLDocument
    If subpage Is Nothing Then
    Else
        Set objpage = subpage.Document
        'Debug.Print objpage
        'objpage.getElementById("content").Click
        Set dl = objpage.getElementsbyclassname("subtable")
        Set dltable = dl(0).FirstChild.ChildNodes
        Set dlrow = dltable(10).getElementsByTagName("a")(2)
        dlrow.Click
        While objpage.ReadyState <> "complete"
            DoEvents
        Wend
    End If
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    Set o = New CUIAutomation
    h = subpage.Hwnd
    fnb = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)
    If fnb = 0 Then Exit Sub
    'Debug.Print "type of fnb is " & TypeName(fnb)
    Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal fnb)
    'Debug.Print "type of e is " & TypeName(e)
    Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Save")
    Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)
    'Debug.Print "type of Button is " & TypeName(Button)
    Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
    'Debug.Print "type of InvokePattern is " & TypeName(InvokePattern)
    InvokePattern.Invoke

End Sub
```

I have tried changing `"Save"` to `"Save as"` but it doesn't work. My guess is that I need to somehow be able to click on the arrow on the split button first before accessing to the save as button but I have had no success in doing it.
Gladly appreciate it if someone can offer a solution.

Comment: Some hints on the code: 1) The lines `Set subpage = New InternetExplorer` and `Set objpage = New HTMLDocument` are unnecessary. 2) Put `Set objallwindows = objshell.Windows ... For Each ow In objallwindows ... Next` block into `Do ... Loop`, add `Exit Do` line after `Set subpage = ow`, also add `DoEvents` somewhere. 3) Then `If subpage Is Nothing Then` is also unnecessary.

Comment: Could you provide more details what data you are trying to download and where from? May be there is another solution could be found, more reliable and which doesn't need IE at all.

Answer (score 0):

I tried simply to download a file by the link http://www.tvsubtitles.net/download-114117.html, which can be found on the webpage http://www.tvsubtitles.net/subtitle-114117.html, and it worked for me, here is the code:

```vb
Sub Test_download_tvsubtitles_net()

    DownloadFile "http://www.tvsubtitles.net/download-114117.html", ThisWorkbook.Path & "\download-114117.zip"

End Sub

Sub DownloadFile(sUrl, sPath)

    Dim aBody

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", sUrl, False
        .Send
        aBody = .responseBody
    End With
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = 1 ' adTypeBinary
        .Open
        .Write aBody
        .SaveToFile sPath, 2 ' adSaveCreateOverWrite
        .Close
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks omegastripes!

Comment: Thanks omegastripes! The thing is that I would need to apply this at work, and that the files that I need to download at work needs to be downloaded via the frame notification bar (because basically I am not clicking a download link but rather downloading the content of a page as a .txt file with customised delimiter etc.)  Do you think that's possible to do with your method? Thanks again.

Comment: @bangbangjim It's not quite clear why do you need to download via the frame notification bar, you wrote that you are not clicking a download link, but actually that is exactly what your code does `dlrow.Click`. My question is what is the difference in files downloaded using your code (I have checked - it works fine) and the above code?

Comment: i did that dlrow.click just to press the download link so a frame notification bar would pop up and I can work on it at home.